# Font changes in `tikz`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pythagwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\pythagheight}{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate [label={below right:$A$}] (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate [label={above right:$B$}] (B) at (0, \pythagheight);
  \coordinate [label={below left:$C$}] (C) at (-\pythagwidth, 0);

  \coordinate (D1) at (-\pythagheight, \pythagheight + \pythagwidth);
  \coordinate (D2) at (-\pythagheight - \pythagwidth, \pythagwidth);

  \draw [thick,red] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (A);

  \newcommand{\ranglesize}{0.3cm}
  \draw [red] (A) -- ++ (0, \ranglesize) -- ++ (-\ranglesize, 0) -- ++ (0, -\ranglesize);

  \draw [help lines] (A) -- node [below] {$b$} ++ (-\pythagwidth, 0)
            -- node [right] {$b$} ++ (0, -\pythagwidth)
            -- node [above] {$b$} ++ (\pythagwidth, 0)
            -- node [left]  {$b$} ++ (0, \pythagwidth);

  \draw [help lines] (A) -- node [right] {$c$} ++ (0, \pythagheight)
            -- node [below] {$c$} ++ (\pythagheight, 0)
            -- node [left]  {$c$} ++ (0, -\pythagheight)
            -- node [above] {$c$} ++ (-\pythagheight, 0);

  \draw [help lines] (C) -- node [above left]  {$a$} (B)
                 -- node [below left]  {$a$} (D1)
                 -- node [below right] {$a$} (D2)
                 -- node [above right] {$a$} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the typeface of the labels to Biolinum, which is the sans-serif typeface in the `libertine` package. I tried `\usepackage{libertine}` and `\sffamily`, which didn't work. I also tried declaring `libertine` as an option on the document class. That didn't work either. What should I do instead?

Comment: Your labels are set in maths mode. You have only issued fonts affecting the text fonts. But if you want them to be in the default `\sffamily`, then the easiest thing would be to just not use maths mode since you don't need it to typeset plain letters unless you want them to come from the maths alphabet, which you don't. So just write e.g. `a` instead of `$a$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your labels are set in maths mode. You have only issued commands affecting only the text fonts. But if you want the labels to be in the default `sffamily`, then the easiest thing would be to just not use maths mode since you don't need it to typeset plain letters unless you want them to come from the maths alphabet, which you don't. So just write e.g. `a` instead of `$a$`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pythagwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\pythagheight}{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

  \coordinate [label={below right:A}] (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate [label={above right:B}] (B) at (0, \pythagheight);
  \coordinate [label={below left:C}] (C) at (-\pythagwidth, 0);

  \coordinate (D1) at (-\pythagheight, \pythagheight + \pythagwidth);
  \coordinate (D2) at (-\pythagheight - \pythagwidth, \pythagwidth);

  \draw [thick,red] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (A);

  \newcommand{\ranglesize}{0.3cm}
  \draw [red] (A) -- ++ (0, \ranglesize) -- ++ (-\ranglesize, 0) -- ++ (0, -\ranglesize);

  \draw [help lines] (A) -- node [below] {b} ++ (-\pythagwidth, 0)
            -- node [right] {b} ++ (0, -\pythagwidth)
            -- node [above] {b} ++ (\pythagwidth, 0)
            -- node [left]  {b} ++ (0, \pythagwidth);

  \draw [help lines] (A) -- node [right] {c} ++ (0, \pythagheight)
            -- node [below] {c} ++ (\pythagheight, 0)
            -- node [left]  {c} ++ (0, -\pythagheight)
            -- node [above] {c} ++ (-\pythagheight, 0);

  \draw [help lines] (C) -- node [above left]  {a} (B)
                 -- node [below left]  {a} (D1)
                 -- node [below right] {a} (D2)
                 -- node [above right] {a} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sans labels]